# Find records in mongo sub-document via unique dates regardless of time

Tags: mongodb

This is somewhat my database record structure.

```
    {
            _id: ObjectId(<some mongo default encoded id>),
        user: 45,
event_group: 1,
            events: [
            {event: "event name", date: ISO(2017-05-11 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name1", date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name2", date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:10:55.774Z)},
            {event: "event name3", date: ISO(2017-05-12 23:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name4", date: ISO(2017-05-12 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name5", date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name6", date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:10:55.774Z)},
            ]
          }

{
            _id: ObjectId(<some mongo default encoded id>),
        user: 45,
event_group: 2,
            events: [
            {event: "event name", date: ISO(2017-05-11 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name1", date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name2", date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:10:55.774Z)},
            {event: "event name3", date: ISO(2017-05-12 23:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name4", date: ISO(2017-05-12 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name5", date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name6", date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:10:55.774Z)},
            ]
          }

{
            _id: ObjectId(<some mongo default encoded id>),
        user: 44,
event_group: 1,
            events: [
            {event: "event name", date: ISO(2017-05-11 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name1", date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name2", date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:10:55.774Z)},
            {event: "event name3", date: ISO(2017-05-12 23:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name4", date: ISO(2017-05-12 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name5", date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name6", date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:10:55.774Z)},
            ]
          }
```

I want to extract the count of days for specific user  (via 'user') regardless of the number of same day entries are there in the database and 'event_group'.

I am using Mongodb 3.4.

### Please note, I won't be changing the data structure in the database.

My output:
 The total is calculating the total records, but I want to count the total as each date should be uniquely counted as one. For example if there are 200 records of 2018-03-11 date then consider them as one.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : null,
    "dates" : [ 
        "2017-09-25", 
        "2017-09-25", 
        "2017-09-25", 
        "2017-09-25",
        "2018-03-15", 
        "2018-03-26", 
        "2018-03-26", 
        "2018-03-28", 
        "2018-03-28", 
        "2017-10-23", 
        "2017-10-23", 
        "2017-10-23", 
        "2017-11-30", 
        "2018-01-14", 
        "2018-01-14", 
        "2018-01-14", 
        "2018-01-17", 
        "2018-01-17", 
        "2018-01-17", 
        "2018-01-19", 
        "2018-01-19", 
        "2018-02-19", 
        "2018-02-19", 
        "2018-02-21", 
        "2018-02-21", 
        "2018-02-21", 
        "2018-02-21", 
        "2018-02-21", 
        "2018-02-22", 
        "2018-02-22",
    ],
    "total" : 9642.0
}
```

Oops!! Its showing the same records now, I think I missed few curly braces, while writing them down in the termial.

Can we count the exact number of dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use:

```
db.users.aggregate([ 
 {$match: {"user": 45}}, 
 {$unwind:"$events"}, 
 {$project: { 
  dateUTC: { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$events.date"}}, 
  "user": 1 
 }}, 
 { $group: { "_id": "$dateUTC","total": { "$sum": 1 }}}, 
 {$group: {_id: 0, "days" :{$sum:1}}} 
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but, I need the count of days from 'date' field not 'event'. For example, if there are 15 entries of 2018-01-14 date (regardless of time) then count it as 1.

Comment: Thanks for replying again.  What is this '$date' operator? I am receiving an exception: invalid operator '$date'"

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have edited my question and added the output and I also updated the query to get the desired outcome. But still I have a query. Can you please check it?

Comment: Oops!! Its showing the same records now, I think I missed few curly braces, while writing them down in the terminal. I have updated my question.

Comment: the output you placed is the output of your query which is very different from what I wrote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168935/discussion-between-graciano-and-hemant-kumar).